# Facebook Marketing API AdImage Upload - Image Resize Failed

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to use image bytes to upload AdImages to the Facebook marketing API. Right now I'm just using the Graph Explorer to test stuff on a Sandbox Account.

I am using the following code to get images as bytes from a URL:

```
$bytes = base64_encode( file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/PATH/TO/image.jpg' ) );
```

When I do so I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1487242,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Image Resize Failed",
        "error_user_msg": "Image Resize Failed:unknown reason",
        "fbtrace_id": "DvqRl8YMleC"
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I reported this as a bug on Facebook, and they have escalated the issue.

Comment: would you mind letting me know where you opened a support ticket for this one? i'm having the same issue, though i am posting, and i can also validate that my base64 encoded string of the image is valid here: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter so i dont know what to do besides open a support ticket

Comment: nevermind it works... i had to uri-encode the base64 string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bytes` parameter will only be accepted if it's a Post parameter.

Comment: I am doing Post yet still getting this error, and am able to validate the 'bytes' is a valid base64 encoded string by pasting it in here: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter any thoughts?